# Serial tower stopped communicating with RCX 1.0

Tags: rcx

I recently bought a RIS 1.5 with brick 1.0 and serial tower (no CD). I got a cheap USB adapter and installed the RIS 2.0. It worked almost fine for a few days. Everytime I started RIS I had to autoconfigure tower, which used COM2. I had to try two or three times to download programs, but it worked.

Later, I installed Bricxcc and connected as well, although I downloaded no program. I did download the original lego firmware with Bricxcc and since then RIS is not able to connect to the RCX.

I have tried with new batteries, uninstalling Bricxcc and then RIS. Installing RIS again, with reboots in the process. Nothing seems to have changed. I cannot connect.

Any previous experience?

I was thinking about buying an USB tower, but I don´t know if it will work with RCX 1.0.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

You could try with [NQC](http://bricxcc.sourceforge.net/nqc/).  By default it supports the Serial Tower and you can specify if you are using a USB Tower with -Susb .  It works on Windows, Linux and Mac.

The man page (documentation) can be found [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nqc) or the in pdf format [here](http://bricxcc.sourceforge.net/nqc/).